# Assets' URLs changing/not changing in CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I can't figure out what made this happen in the first place, and now I can't figure out why it stopped happening.

My CSS is shared across applications and changing it is not an option. I can use different CSS files in development but this mysterious feature was nice while it lasted. It is not created using any asset helper tags.

This is the CSS at it is in on my hard-drive:

```
body .page-background {
  background: #ffffff url(/images/template/css/bg_body.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

And this is how the CSS was appearing on the page:

```
body .page-background {
  background: #ffffff url(/assets/template/css/bg_body.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

So **/images** -> **/assets**.

This was a surprise at first, but it ended up being great because my images actually WERE in /assets when running in the *development* environment. How did Rails know this and why did it stop converting the URL?

I've been searching through Rails' source but I can't find any place that this substitution would have been made.

Rails Verision: 3.2

Comment: In your public/ folder the images are copied or cached but in the assets folder is where rails calls your images. In my app I usually use ../assets to access images in dev and production

Comment: Not all applications accessing the static assets are Rails. Are images still cached in public/ in _development_? I have a server running but don't see anything extra in public/.

Comment: hmm. Is your images folder located within the assets folder such as assets/images/?

Comment: yes it is located there. app/assets/images.

Comment: Rails can access all images within the assets folder. In production you will see /assets as it is what the rails assets pipeline uses.

Comment: My question is related to the changing of the URL in the CSS file.

Comment: Where is the CSS file locally?

Comment: And what is the exact filename of the file? Is it pure CSS, i.e. ".css", or is it being processed, i.e. ".scss", ".css.erb", or something else?

Comment: locally it is in app/assets/stylesheets/global.css. Pure css.